# How can I fix this SVN commit which fails as "out of date"?

Tags: svn

In my repository, I have two revisions. The src code is on revision 2, but I had a file that messed up, so I reverted it to revision 1.

After a few hours of debugging, that javafile works, but I can't commit it. SVN says that the javafile is out of date. This is probably because I'm editing javafile.java rev1, right?

How do I resolve this? I know I could copy/paste my modified javafile rev1 code into its rev2 counterpart, and then commit, but is there another way? Am I using SVN incorrectly?

Comment: Note this is covered in the "basic usage" sections of the SVN book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Updating the working copy should fix it.

From the command line:

```
X:\WorkingCopy>svn up
```

or right-click and choose `SVN Update...` in TortoiseSVN

When you update, you may come across conflicts, which will be marked in your code with

```
>>>>>
...
-----
...
<<<<<
```

You'll need to manually resolve these. When you're done, don't forget to mark the file as resolved.

```
X:\WorkingCopy>svn resolve \path\to\file
```

or right-click and choose `TortoiseSVN -> Mark as Resolved...` in TortoiseSVN

Comment: But what if I've edited some methods, I'll get conflicts errors right? How would I resolve that? :(

Comment: Conflicts mean that you and someone else have made changes to the same bunch of code. You will see >>>>>>  ---------  and <<<<<< markers in your source code now. They show you the different versions of the code. You'll need to sort out with the other developers which code is the correct one.

Comment: You can mostly prevent large, painful conflicts by following the advice: 'commit early, commit often'

Comment: In part it depends on how or what you mean by 'reverting' the file to revision 1.  If you where working on version 2, and dropped a copy of the version 1 file over it, then there will be no update or need to resolve conflicts.  If you set your working revision to 1, then edited and tried to commit, then you get this out of date issue.  Instead you should leave your working revision at the head, and use the revert/merge tool (or drop new content) to remove the change which would be applied to your working version.

Comment: Ty Benny. Got it Greg, I should've udpated the head revision instead of the previous revision TY.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue in Eclipse (Windows 10). It was solved by right clicking on the folder in question > Team > Update to HEAD

Answer (score 4):

Update your working copy, and resolve the merge conflicts by copying the resulting file that has your locally modified version over the version with conflict markers in in. Run `svn resolved` on it, and check that in. This does assume there are no other changes that you want to preserve.