# Subversion workflow: Comparing latest and committing new changes

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to subversion and have a question about working with it in IDEA.

Here's my process in IDEA:

- Try to commit; Failed because local file out of date
- Go to `Subversion > Compare with Latest Repository Version`
- Make changes to working copy so it matches SVN copy, with the exception of my local additions.
- My working copy gets updated with the changes I made in the diff editor.
- Attempt to commit, it still says out of date

Another developer made changes, I updated my local file to reflect his changes in the diff viewer, now my working copy has his changes AND my changes.  My working copy is up to date with both of our changes, how to I get this in?

If I use `Subversion > Update file...`, it will wipe my working copy and replace with latest copy.

What is the correct workflow process here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Svn commit failed out of date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610897/svn-commit-failed-out-of-date)

Answer (score 1):

If you and the other developer did not work on the same location in the file, doing an `svn update` will *not* wipe out your changes. So there's that. As @Ben pointed out, even if you did work on the same location, svn will just ask you to merge the changes by hand (unless it is a binary file).

A better work flow would be to work on separate branches so you don't get in each other's way, or, if that's not possible, manually schedule changes in files you both work on to avoid these kinds of problems in the future.

Comment: Even if you DID work on the same location in the file, SVN won't wipe out your changes. You get a chance to merge. UNLESS it's a binary file that SVN doesn't know how to merge. In that situation, you can just move your file out of the way, do an update, and move your file back in to replace what's there.

Comment: @Ben: Yes of course. However, it seemed to be that the OP was looking for an easy way out. I updated my answer anyways.